# Migrating GWT 2.6 to GWT 2.7

Tags: gwt

Hi I am facing issues while migrating GWT 2.6 to 2.7.
I downloaded the GWT 2.7 SDK and add it to the web toolkit in project from build path.
But while compiling I am facing the below errors.

```
[ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
    /**com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:121)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:296)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:67)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:145)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:600)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:569)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1505)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:870)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1305)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1038)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:954)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:303)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:38)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:286)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.<init>(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/PropertyOracle;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/GeneratorContext;)V
        at org.atmosphere.gwt20.rebind.SerializerGenerator.generateIncrementally(SerializerGenerator.java:88)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:754)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
        ... 40 more
          [ERROR] at MainEntryPoint.java(122): GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class)
             com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
          [ERROR] at MainEntryPoint.java(122): (RPCSerializer) GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class)
             com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
          [ERROR] at MainEntryPoint.java(122): RPCSerializer rpc_serializer = (RPCSerializer) GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class)
             com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
          [ERROR] at MainEntryPoint.java(121): {
      RPCSerializer rpc_serializer = (RPCSerializer) GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class);
      MainEntryPoint.logger.info(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()); **/
```

Comment: have you tried to delete the GWT-UnitCache?

Comment: yes I already tried that,but nothing happend :(

Comment: Have you checked if there are two versions of gwt in your classpath?

Comment: No I have only one version of GWT SDK 2.7 in my class path.

Comment: In logs "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.<init>(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/PropertyOracle;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/GeneratorContext;)",looks like creating problem in compiling code in gwt 2.7,I am not sure .Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Which version of org.atmosphere.gwt20 do you use? You may also need to update this library.

Comment: atmosphere-gwt-2.2.0 version jars I am using.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is org.atmosphere.gwt20.rebind.SerializerGenerator, a generator that is NOT part of GWT and seems that have been compiled against an older version of GWT. It needs to be recompiled against GWT 2.7 for it to work.

Comment: I did the  clean build and also updated to atmosphere to 2.2.0 ,but still facing compiling issue.